How do I setup a ConPTY using PowerShell v5.1?
I'm looking for a a way to have PowerShell v5.1 send output to different windows not using WinForms, WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) or a new PowerShell process involving Named Pipes (IPC) keeping it simple and fast.
Now in windows, the CONHOST is "hidden" behind a commandline interface such as cmd.exe or PowerShell.exe. I did find some references about using CONHOST but that involves crude methods such as [SendKeys] which isn't very foolproof or streaming content from a file.
However, since Windows 10, there is a new kid on the block. Namely ConPTY that do support console remoting.
I did manage to get hold on some sample code but it keeps failing on the InteropService part in section four below...
And I don't speak C# :/
Now this isn't very "simple" but, on the other hand, very interesting.
1. Define the Pseudo Console Functions
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class PseudoConsole
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreatePseudoConsole(COORD size, IntPtr hInput, IntPtr hOutput, uint dwFlags, out IntPtr phPC);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool ClosePseudoConsole(IntPtr hPC);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct COORD
    {
        public short X;
        public short Y;
    }
}
"@


2. Create the Pseudo Console
$coord = New-Object PseudoConsole+COORD
$coord.X = 80
$coord.Y = 25

$inputPipe = [System.IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeServerStream]::new([System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::In)
$outputPipe = [System.IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeServerStream]::new([System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::Out)

$hPC = [IntPtr]::Zero
[PseudoConsole]::CreatePseudoConsole($coord, $inputPipe.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), $outputPipe.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), 0, [ref]$hPC)


3. Define the Process Creation Functions
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class ProcessHelper
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CreateProcess(
        string lpApplicationName,
        string lpCommandLine,
        IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
        IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
        bool bInheritHandles,
        uint dwCreationFlags,
        IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        string lpCurrentDirectory,
        [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public uint cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public uint dwX;
        public uint dwY;
        public uint dwXSize;
        public uint dwYSize;
        public uint dwXCountChars;
        public uint dwYCountChars;
        public uint dwFillAttribute;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public ushort wShowWindow;
        public ushort cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public uint dwProcessId;
        public uint dwThreadId;
    }
}
"@


4. Start the Process and Attach to the Pseudo Console
$si = New-Object ProcessHelper+STARTUPINFO
$pi = New-Object ProcessHelper+PROCESS_INFORMATION

$si.cb = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf([ProcessHelper+STARTUPINFO])
$si.hStdInput = $inputPipe.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle()
$si.hStdOutput = $outputPipe.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle()
$si.hStdError = $outputPipe.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle()
$si.dwFlags = 0x00000100 # STARTF_USESTDHANDLES

[ProcessHelper]::CreateProcess(
    $null,
    "cmd.exe",
    [IntPtr]::Zero,
    [IntPtr]::Zero,
    $true,
    0,
    [IntPtr]::Zero,
    $null,
    [ref]$si,
    [ref]$pi
)


Line 3 in section 4 will break with

Exception calling "SizeOf" with "1" argument(s): "Type 'System.RuntimeType' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed."
At line:1 char:1
$si.cb = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf([ProcessHel ...
    CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException  
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException  


I might add that I need this to work using a plain user account.

Don't use non-existent tags. The post shows a lot of misconceptions - no, the Console API isn't hidden behind a shell. CMD and Powershell are shells. The old Console and Windows Terminal are the actual terminals/consoles that connect to the shells. You don't need to start a terminal to connect to a process's STDIN/STDOUT.

Well, feel free to enlighten me :)

@PanagiotisKanavos: Irrespective of whether creating a new tag was warranted or not in a given scenario: Please don't make categorical statements such as "Don't use non-existent tags". If people were to follow this advice, no new tags would ever be created - which is obviously to the detriment of the community at large. Instead, if someone creates a tag that is useful, but without also creating info for it (at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/<tag>/info - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/conpty/info in the case at hand), encourage them to do the latter.

@mklement0 how many times did we have to burninate tags this year because people just added a tag at random? Or didn't check if there was a relevant tag? In any case, I wasn't interested in making blanket statements at the time, I was looking for the articles that describe the current terminal architecture.

The current Console architecture is explained in short in Scott Hanselman's What's the difference between a Console and a Shell. ConPTY isn't the console, it's the thing that connects consoles to apps. The question is asking how to create consoles for different outputs and connect to them - which is a rather weird choice even for text applications. Even in the DOS era people used multiple panes for multiple output. Nowadays that's possible using the Spectre.Console and Gui.cs libraries

The tag was removed so that is a non-topic :)


This may not solve your problem overall, but the immediate problem with your code is that you're trying to pass a type rather than an instance to [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf(), which - while supported in principle - doesn't work from PowerShell as-is, due to how PowerShell performs method overload resolution.
You have the following options:

Instead of passing [ProcessHelper+STARTUPINFO], pass $si, i.e. the instance of that type that you've constructed:
$si.cb = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($si)


Alternatively, match the method overload signature exactly, by using a [type] cast:
$si.cb = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf([type] [ProcessHelper+STARTUPINFO])


This avoids the problem of PowerShell's method overload resolution not choosing the System.Type overload, possibly due to mistakenly trying the
generic overload with the non-public System.RuntimeType type that [...] PowerShell type literals evaluate to (try [int].GetType().FullName; said type is non-public, but indirectly derives from the public System.Type, via another public type,  System.Reflection.TypeInfo.
See GitHub issue #10664 for a discussion.


Yet another alternative, only available in PowerShell (Core) 7 in v7.3+ is to use the generic method overload, using the PowerShell 7.3+ support for calling generic methods (note that the type literal is specified as a generic type argument, as part of the method name, and that no argument is passed (())):
$si.cb = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf[ProcessHelper+STARTUPINFO]()




Thx. No errors this time around. But still no interactive cmd.exe shell to attach to, which I was aiming ultimately... So I can't easily tell if I've got a working ConPTY attached or not.

ConPTY is a virtual console and doesn't display a window.
It can however be attached to an existing console, but Windows has to my knowledge some severe restrictions on interacting with redirection of standard input/output in interactive mode.
So all of my attempts so far has failed.

I wonder if yours is a XY problem: You think that ConPTY is the solution to your problem, but it may not be. What applications do you envision to be running in the visible target windows, and how do you expect to provide input to them that surfaces visibly, keeping in mind that they may be in a state where they're not ready to accept such input?

Your point is correct. I'm using WinForms instead. I just had a vision of very simple output to multiple console windows ;)

If sending startup commands to multiple console (terminal) windows you create (and which of necessity are running shells) is sufficient, you could consider wt.exe, the Windows Terminal CLI; there's also a wrapper with a simpler CLI, wttab.

Interesting, but WT isn't available for previous versions of Windows Server :/

Bummer. You could try calling conhost.exe directly (may require the equivalent of at least Windows 10, i.e. Windows Server 2016), e.g. conhost powershell -NoExit -Command "Get-Date"

I'm able to start the conhost. But I'd like to pipe or redirect output to it. That was why I was trying to work with ConPTY attachment.
